# How to save the selected indexpaths of an UICollectionViewCell which is inside a UITableViewCell to an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have UICollectionViewCells inside the UITableView. I am trying to highlight the selected UICollectionViewCell for of each row the UITableView. When the UITableView reloads the selected cells should be highlighted. Here is sample code:

```
var selectedIndexes = [IndexPath]()
var familyAModelArray : [[Child1]] = []
var childAModelArray : [Child1] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return familyAModelArray[collectionView.tag].count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChildCollectionViewCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = childAModelArray[indexPath.row].person! // or childArray

        cell.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(baseUrl)\(childAModelArray[indexPath.row].image!)"), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar.png"), options: [.continueInBackground,.progressiveDownload])

     return cell
        }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)

        let i = selectedIndexes[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row]

}
```

Here i got Index out of range:`let i = selectedIndexes[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row]`

How to achieve this?Any Idea?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than saving index paths in an extra array add a property to your data model to indicate the `selected` state.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the reply. if i add a property to data model to indicate selected state as bool how can i access it from the didSelectItemAt indexPath function?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to check if your cells are being selected is to change the background color of the cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAt(indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    // append the selected red cells to an array like such
    selectedIndices.append(indexPath)


}
```

Once the tableView reloads you can check your array for selected indexes and change the background color.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChildCollectionViewCell

    if selectedIndices.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        // check if the index matches a selectedIndex and change it to the selected color.
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = childAModelArray[indexPath.row].person! // or childArray

    cell.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(baseUrl)\(childAModelArray[indexPath.row].image!)"), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar.png"), options: [.continueInBackground,.progressiveDownload])

 return cell
}
```

Now once it reloads, the cellForItemAt function is called again and the indices at the selected index paths will be red again.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the way you tell which cell is tapped. Just check which tableView row is selected with the didSelectRow function for the table view.